# I want my navigation bar in horizontal but it is vertical

Tags: html, css

[image: see the pic here]

Please help through this problem to bring in horizontal navigation

The code is:-

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " id="menu">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse move-me">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['loggedin_name']; ?></a></li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="attendance.php">ATTENDANCE </a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.php">PROFILE </a></li>
        <li><a href="facultypage.php">TIMETABLE</a></li>
        <li><a href="statistics.php"> STATISTICS</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you are using the latest Bootstrap?

I think you have to add navbar-default to your `<div class="navbar">` and navbar-nav to your `<ul class="nav">`

```
<div class="container">
  <h1><a href="#">Bootstrap Site</a></h1>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="attendance.php">ATTENDANCE </a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.php">PROFILE </a></li>
        <li><a href="facultypage.php">TIMETABLE</a></li>
        <li><a href="statistics.php"> STATISTICS</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this  bootstrap cdn link it will work.

**`<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`**